# Normalized file path comparison in Powershell

Tags: powershell, path, equality

Say I have the following two paths (both are valid, say):

```
$p1 = "D:\folder1\"
$p2 = "D:\Folder1"
```

I want to compare these two paths for equality. I am expecting both paths to be the same. I tried both the commands below:

- `(Resolve-Path $p1) -eq (Resolve-Path $p2)`
- (`Get-Item $p1) -eq (Get-Item $p2)`

None returned `$True` because the backslash was not normalized. Now I know I can do some regex magic and make it work but all I am looking for is an in-built solution for comparing file paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
join-path "C:\Windows" ""
join-path "C:\Windows\" ""
```

Both return "C:\Windows\" since join-path normalizes them.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

***`Join-Path (Resolve-Path $Path).ProviderPath ''`***

Assuming a folder named `folder1` exists in the root of `D:\`, this:

```
Set-Location -Path 'D:\'
"\\$([Environment]::MachineName)\D$\folder1",
"\\$([Environment]::MachineName)\D$\folder1\",
'D:\folder1\',
  '\folder1\',
   'folder1\',
'D:\folder1' ,
  '\folder1' ,
   'folder1' | ForEach-Object {
    Join-Path (Resolve-Path $_).ProviderPath ''
}
```

Returns this:

```
\\<ComputerName>\D$\folder1\
\\<ComputerName>\D$\folder1\
D:\folder1\
D:\folder1\
D:\folder1\
D:\folder1\
D:\folder1\
D:\folder1\
```