# How to normalize and compare paths in Powershell

Tags: powershell, path

I need to test two strings, which contain paths, for wether they point to the same directory or not.
Simply using a string comparison fails when comparing `C:\Windows` with `C:\Windows\` for example.

This problem can be solved by using Join-Path as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787604/normalized-file-path-comparison-in-powershell) StackOverflow-Question, but it still leaves out other things:
For example `\\server\share` can sometimes be represented as `UNC\server\share` or `\\<ip>\share`

Is there a proper way to check this without using a workaround?

EDIT:
I have implemented the code found in my answer in my powershell module PSHelperTools which can be downloaded using `Install-Module PSHelperTools`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to normalize a path in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495618/how-to-normalize-a-path-in-powershell)

Comment: `UNC\server\share` is _not_ a UNC path, it's just a relative local path. Did you mean `\\.\UNC\server\share`?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it does not work for my case, since as mathias mentioned, it gets recognized as relative local path

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen where i got that format from is symlinks linking to a share as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/MOaEPYO)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Didn't you mean `\\?\UNC\server\share` ?

Comment: @Theo No I meant `\\.\UNC\server\share` :) But both examples are rooted == valid UNC paths

Comment: So, there is clearly not a cmdlet that can check this for you, specially checking if a non valid UNC path is actually UNC. What have you tried? Share your code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i used `((Get-Item $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Target) -replace "^UNC\\","\\")` to manually remove the UNC, and just manually not adding a backslash at the end of the paths.

I know that it is possible, that is not my question. My question is if there is a *proper* way to achieve it using an official cmdlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am using this as a workaround:

```
function Format-Path(){
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    param($Path)

    Write-Verbose "Format-Path: $Path"
    if($Path.StartsWith(".")){
        #Get Absolute path if path starts with "."
        $Path = Resolve-Path -Path $Path
        Write-Verbose "Resolved Path: $Path"
    }
    if($Path -match "^.*::(.*)"){
        $Path = $Path -replace "^.*::(.*)", '$1'
        Write-Verbose "Replaced Powershell providers: $Path"
    }
    $Path = $Path -replace "/"                      , "\" `
                  -replace "^\\\\\.\\"              , "" `
                  -replace "^\\\\\?\\"              , "" `
                  -replace "^UNC\\"                 , "\\"
    Write-Verbose "Replaced UNC conventions: $Path"

    if($Path -match "^\\\\([A-Za-z]+)(@SSL)?"){
        $Path = $Path -replace "^\\\\([A-Za-z]+)(@SSL)?", "\\$((Resolve-DnsName $matches[1] -Type "A").IPAddress)"
        Write-Verbose "Resolve name into IP: $Path"
    }

    return $Path.TrimEnd("\")
}
```

Comment: That trim at the end might cause problems if it is the root of a drive!

Answer (score 0):

There's a proper way of doing that, as you can see in this mess https://stackoverflow.com/a/74201349/1964796

None of the answers there are entirely acceptable for the following reasons.

- It must support powershell providers.
- It must work for paths that don't exist in drives that don't exist.
- It must process ".." and ".", that's what a normalized path is.
- No external libraries, and no regex.
- It mustn't reroot the path, this means relative paths stay relative.

For the following reasons, I made a list of the expected results you get for each method listed here, as follows:

```
function tests {
    context "cwd" {
        it 'has no external libraries' {
            Load-NormalizedPath
        }
        it 'barely work for FileInfos on existing paths' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'a\..\c' | should -be 'c'
        }
        it 'process .. and . (relative paths)' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'a\b\..\..\c\.' | should -be 'c'
        }
        it 'must support powershell providers' {
            Get-NormalizedPath "FileSystem::\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Shared\a\..\c" | should -be "FileSystem::\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Shared\c"
        }
        it 'must support powershell drives' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'HKLM:\Software\Classes\.exe\..\.dll' | should -be 'HKLM:\Software\Classes\.dll'
        }
        it 'works with non-existant paths' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'fred\frog\..\frag\.' | should -be 'fred\frag'
        }
        it 'works with non-existant drives' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'U:\fred\frog\..\frag\.' | should -be 'U:\fred\frag'
        }
        it 'barely work for direct UNCs' {
            Get-NormalizedPath "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Shared\a\..\c" | should -be "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Shared\c"
        }
    }
    context "reroot" {
        it 'doesn''t reroot subdir' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'fred\frog\..\frag\.' | should -be 'fred\frag'
        }
        it 'doesn''t reroot local' {
            Get-NormalizedPath '.\fred\frog\..\frag\.' | should -be 'fred\frag'
        }
        it 'doesn''t reroot parent' {
            Get-NormalizedPath "..\$((Get-Item .).Name)\fred\frog\..\frag\." | should -be 'fred\frag'
        }
    }
    context "drive root" {
        beforeEach { Push-Location 'c:/' }
        it 'works on drive root' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'fred\frog\..\..\fred\frag\' | should -be 'fred\frag\'
        }
        afterEach { Pop-Location }
    }
    context "temp drive" {
        beforeEach { New-PSDrive -Name temp -PSProvider FileSystem 'b:/tools' }
        it 'works on temp drive' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'fred\frog\..\..\fred\frag\' | should -be 'fred\frag\'
        }
        it 'works on temp drive with absolute path' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'temp:\fred\frog\..\..\fred\frag\' | should -be 'temp:\fred\frag\'
        }
        afterEach { Remove-PSDrive -Name temp }
    }
    context "unc drive" {
        beforeEach { Push-Location "FileSystem::\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Shared\​" }
        it 'works on unc drive' {
            Get-NormalizedPath 'fred\frog\..\..\fred\frag\' | should -be 'fred\frag\'
        }
        afterEach { Pop-Location }
    }
}
```

The correct answer uses `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath`, but it can't work on its own, if you try using it directly, you get those results.
From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157943/1964796 .

```
$path = Join-Path '/' $path
$path = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)
$path = $path.Replace($pwd.Path, '').Replace($pwd.Drive.Root, '')
```

```
pros: simple
cons: needs boilerplate to make it correct, doesn't work with other providers or non-ex drives.

 Context cwd
   [+] has no external libraries 4ms (1ms|3ms)
   [+] barely work for FileInfos on existing paths 3ms (2ms|0ms)
   [+] process .. and . (relative paths) 3ms (2ms|0ms)
   [-] must support powershell providers 4ms (3ms|1ms)
    Expected: 'FileSystem::\\LUIZMONAD\Shared\c'
    But was:  '\\LUIZMONAD\Shared\a\..\c'
               ^
   [-] must support powershell drives 14ms (4ms|10ms)
    Expected: 'HKLM:\Software\Classes\.dll'
    But was:  'Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '\HKLM' does not exist.'
               ^
   [+] works with non-existant paths 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [-] works with non-existant drives 4ms (3ms|1ms)
    Expected: 'U:\fred\frag'
    But was:  'Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '\U' does not exist.'
               ^
   [-] barely work for direct UNCs 3ms (3ms|1ms)
    Expected: '\\LUIZMONAD\Shared\c'
    But was:  '\\LUIZMONAD\Shared\a\..\c'
               -------------------^
 Context reroot
   [+] doesn't reroot subdir 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] doesn't reroot local 33ms (33ms|1ms)
   [-] doesn't reroot parent 4ms (3ms|1ms)
    Expected: 'fred\frag'
    But was:  '\fred\frag'
               ^
 Context drive root
   [+] works on drive root 5ms (3ms|2ms)
 Context temp drive
   [+] works on temp drive 4ms (3ms|1ms)
   [-] works on temp drive with absolute path 6ms (5ms|1ms)
    Expected: 'temp:\fred\frag\'
    But was:  'Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '\temp' does not exist.'
               ^
 Context unc drive
   [+] works on unc drive 6ms (5ms|1ms)
Tests completed in 207ms
Tests Passed: 9, Failed: 6, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

So, what we need to do is to strip the driver/provider/unc and then use the `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` and then put the driver/provider/unc back.
Unfortunately *GetUPPFP* depends on the current `pwd` state, but we at least aren't changing it.

```
$path_drive = [ref] $null
$path_abs = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.IsPSAbsolute($path, $path_drive)
$path_prov = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.IsProviderQualified($path)
# we split the drive away, it makes UnresolvedPath fail on non-existing drives.
$norm_path  = Split-Path $path -NoQualifier
# strip out UNC
$path_direct = $norm_path.StartsWith('//') -or $norm_path.StartsWith('\\')
if ($path_direct) {
    $norm_path = $norm_path.Substring(2)
}
# then normalize
$norm_path = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($norm_path)
# then we cut out the current location if same drive
if (($path_drive.Value -eq $pwd.Drive.Name) -or $path_direct) {
    $norm_path = $norm_path.Substring($pwd.Path.Trim('/', '\').Length + 1)
} elseif (-not $path_prov) {
    # or we cut out the current drive
    if ($pwd.Drive) {
        $norm_path = $norm_path.Substring($pwd.Drive.Root.Length)
    } else {
        # or we cut out the UNC special case
        $norm_path = $norm_path.Substring($pwd.ProviderPath.Length + 1)
    }
}
# then add back the UNC if any
if ($path_direct) {
    $norm_path = $pwd.Provider.ItemSeparator + $pwd.Provider.ItemSeparator + $norm_path
}
# then add back the provider if any
if ($path_prov) {
    $norm_path = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.Combine($path_drive.Value + '::/', $norm_path)
}
# or add back the drive if any
elseif ($path_abs) {
    $norm_path = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.Combine($path_drive.Value + ':', $norm_path)
}
$norm_path
```

```
pros: doesn't use the dotnet path function, uses proper powershell infrastructure.
cons: kind of complex, depends on `pwd`

 Context cwd
   [+] has no external libraries 8ms (2ms|6ms)
   [+] barely work for FileInfos on existing paths 4ms (3ms|1ms)
   [+] process .. and . (relative paths) 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] must support powershell providers 13ms (13ms|0ms)
   [+] must support powershell drives 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] works with non-existant paths 3ms (2ms|0ms)
   [+] works with non-existant drives 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] barely work for direct UNCs 3ms (2ms|1ms)
 Context reroot
   [+] doesn't reroot subdir 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] doesn't reroot local 3ms (2ms|1ms)
   [+] doesn't reroot parent 15ms (14ms|1ms)
 Context drive root
   [+] works on drive root 4ms (3ms|1ms)
 Context temp drive
   [+] works on temp drive 4ms (3ms|1ms)
   [+] works on temp drive with absolute path 3ms (3ms|1ms)
 Context unc drive
   [+] works on unc drive 9ms (8ms|1ms)
Tests completed in 171ms
Tests Passed: 15, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Sources and tests:
https://gist.github.com/Luiz-Monad/d5aea290087a89c070da6eec84b33742#file-normalize-path-ps-md